# KVM secure buffer for internet traffic

Tags: networking, security, kvm-virtualization, virtualization

I am running ubuntu 16.04 and am relatively new to virtual machine setup.
After my machine was hacked, a windows friend suggested a virtual machine setup with a riverbed that would inspect network connections.
I have a dynamic IP address allocated by provider and I'm not actually running a server, It's just a home machine.

My question is how to configure this setup so that I have incoming traffic diverted there for inspection and protect another environment from which I work? 
 Thanks